# How can I enable emails for my Sylius projects? (Symfony)

Tags: email, sylius

I installed [Sylius](http://sylius.org/) using the documentation:

http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/book/index.html#installation

Everything seems to work fine as you can see there:

http://sylius.krown.ch/app_dev.php/en_US/

```
Laurence
4567
```

Except with emails. I just want to enable default emails, as described there. Unfortunately no email is sent my the website after an order confirmation for example.

I have several projects installed in my server, including Symfony projects. Usually emails work just fine

How can I enable emails for my Sylius projects?

Answer (score 2):

check your config_dev.yml if you have disabled mail delivery for dev environment:

```
swiftmailer:
    disable_delivery: true
```